# Patch request in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, patch

I am trying to make a patch request in flutter and in the body I write my values as:

```
body: {
"var" : [v]
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your data to JSON using `json.encode:`

```
import 'dart:convert';

body: json.encode({"var" : [v]});
```